# Integrate paypal donation with venmo

Tags: paypal, venmo

I have a donation button on a site which links to a paypal account so people can donation via paypal.  How can I set up the same but allow the donation to be made via Venmo?  I played around with paypal transactions (instead of donation) and the iframe string that gets passed to paypal includes switches which instruct paypal to render the paypal, pay later, venmo, and credit/debit buttons.  Is there something similar for donations so the user can pay with venmo?

Answer (score 0):

The PayPal donations flow does not support Venmo.

You can create a non-donation button for Venmo payments. If you want to render only a Venmo payment button using PayPal, see [Standalone buttons](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/standard/customize/standalone-buttons/).